# sharepoint 2013 calendar and CQWP weekly or week number filter

Tags: calendar

I'm using a sharepoint 2013 calendar list to enter event of my company.

Like XX/XX/2015 - Meeting
     XX/XX/2015 - Big Party

I would like to display them on the home page like a mini calendar.

I need a weekly view of my events

I'm trying to achieve this using the CQWP, but I'm not able to filter only event for the current week.

I have also tried add a site column with the week number and filter on it, but also unable to filter on the dynamic value of the week number.

May the content search more useful ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally  found the solution.

I used a content search instead of cqwp, in the KQL query I used the keyword this week on a date field to filter my records.

see keyword query language syntax reference for sp2013  on Microsoft site.

That's it.

Regards